# Flutter Have a loading icon on the fetched data instead of a whole Circular Progress Indicator screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a screen witch is a login screen, and after the login screen, at the other screen data is going to be fetched. In the future builder i return a Circular Progress Indicator at the end witch while the data is being fetched, this Circular Progress Indicator takes a whole screen with the progress indicator spinning, and i dont want that, i need the user to see the screen, and i want to have a loading icon or loading text while the data is being fetched, so this loading icon or loading text is gonna be shown until the data is fetched. So i dont want a whole screen of a loading screen instead i want to show to the user what i want from that other screen and just have a loading icon or text that shows where the data is going to be fetched and just have this loading icon till the data is fetched instead of a whole screen.

```
child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: FutureBuilder<List<Response>>(
              future: Future.wait([futureData, futureDataForAccount]),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<WorkingLocationData> data1 =
                      parsedData(snapshot.data![0].body);
                  data = data1;

                  AccountData data3 =
                      AccountData.fromJson(json.decode(snapshot.data![1].body));

                  return Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          width: width,
                          height: 50,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              width: 4,
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                        'Welcome ' + data3.firstName + ' ${data3.lastName}', // data being fetched
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          ))),
                      const Text(
                        'Choose working location',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
                          value: chooseLocation,
                          hint: const Text('Select a location'),
                          isExpanded: true,
                          items: data.map((some) {
                          items: data!.map((some) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                             child: Text(some.name + ' (${some.location})'), // data being fetched
                              value: some.name,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: const Text(
                            'Submit',
                            'Start Work',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: height* 0.001,)
                    ],
                   );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); // i dont want to have this
              },
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar1(context)),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

snapshot.hasData ? fetchedData : CircularIndicator